# How to use group route in vue js like laravel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel-5, vuejs2

I want something like this.

```
Route.group({ prefix: '/blog' }, () => {
    Route.view('/', 'PostIndex');        // '/blog/posts'
    Route.view('/create', 'CreatePost'); // '/blog/posts/create'
    Route.view('/edit', 'EditPost');     // '/blog/posts/edit'
});
```

I am using vue-router in laravel app.

Answer (score 2):

[Nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) might be able to get you there but i have a feeling they won't be a correct fit for you. Your example in Laravel just handles a prefix on all the routes where as the nested routes wraps all of the children routes in a parent layout.

You could probably achieve something similar just by creating a simple function:

```
const routesWithPrefix = (prefix, routes) => {
  return routes.map(route => {
    route.path = `${prefix}${route.path}`

    return route
  })
}

{
  routes: [
    {
      path: 'another-route',
      component: AnotherComponent
    },
    ...routesWithPrefix('/blog', [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: PostIndex
      },
      {
        path: '/create',
        component: CreatePost
      },
      {
        path: '/edit',
        component: EditPost
      }
    ])
  ]
}
```

I personally would just write out the prefix manually but this closer emulates what you're getting in Laravel.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nested routes. [Have a look here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

Comment: Nested routes is not what the author asked for. He wants to set a base path for a bunch of routes. With nested routes you can use `<router-view>` inside a router-view.

Comment: Yes, I understand nested routes was not the best fit for the author's situation, but given the time and resources available at the time when this question was posted, nested routes was the closest the author could've used, or create a custom function like Dan suggested in their answer.